# Possibly unhandled Error when returning promise inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have the following code:

```
SuccessfulPromise().then(function() {
    return rejectedPromise();
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Is it intentional that i get the above error message or is it an error? The error gets handled in the catch block and although this i get the error message `Possibly unhandled Error`.

Comment: Can you please give an working example?

Comment: After a successful promise in the then function i return a rejected promise with Promise.reject(). It is in a test so everything is mocked out.

Comment: The outer catch block catches the returned rejected promise inside the then function, but still gets the Possibly unhandled error to the console

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please show the code of `rejectedPromise` - this won't reproduce with `return Promise.reject()`

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> The problem was with `sinon.stub().returns(Promise.rejected('error'))`. The promise got executed before assigned to an error handler.

I'd like to point out that this is correct. When a promise is rejected, Bluebird checks the chain to see if any error handlers will handle it, and if not it will trigger the `possiblyUnhandledRejection` event. So if the rejection happens before having assigned a handler, you get a "false report".

However! There is a reason it's called *possibly*: The system still detects handling of that error once you *do* assign a handler to it, and it will then trigger an `UnhandledRejectionHandled` event [as documented](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/ca0f2f8b204df7015eb1f7b75ba8195a81bf0d7e/API.md#promiseonunhandledrejectionhandledfunction-handler---undefined). You can use the latter event to ensure that you are not bothered with false unhandled rejections past the point of handling them.

Comment: Thank you, this led me to my answer. I ended rewriting my `onPossiblyUnhandledRejection` event handler to not print anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with
`sinon.stub().returns(Promise.rejected('error'))`.
The promise got executed before assigned to an error handler.

Comment: Oh, so it was the same rejected promise and it was duplicated several times?

Comment: it wasnt duplicated, just didnt get its error handler when it was craeted

Comment: Can you create a complete verifiable code sample and open an issue please (or update the issue you closed and we'll reopen it?)

Comment: Thank you. Having the same problem. How did you fix it? I mean I don't want to get that ugly error message.